# "em lugar de" vs "em vez de"

Tags: ortografia, expressões

Qual é diferença entre **em lugar de** e **em vez de**?

Pelo texto os dois significam "in stead of!" Está certo?

Comment: A qual texto, exatamente, te referes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os dois são sinônimos, contudo "em vez de" tem caráter 'coloquial' sendo mais usado em linguagem falada, enquanto 'em lugar de' tem caráter formal.
Outra expressão semelhante, usada em linguagem formal "ao invés de". São semelhantes a "instead of".

Comment: _ao invés de_ significa outra coisa e _in spite of_ ainda outra diferente.

Comment: Sim, de fato in spite of é diferente, corrigi. Contudo "ao invés de" me parece semelhante às outras duas. Em que sentido é diferente?

Comment: _ao invés de_ significa _contrariamente a_. Há uma ideia de oposição. https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/1384

Comment: Quando você diz 'significa', quer me parecer que teja criando uma espécie de 'categoria de igualdade', o que não é bem 'verdade'. Por exemplo, a ideia de oposição não 'significa' exatamente a ideia de contrário, embora sejam bastante semelhantes. Neste site que você citou, dá pra ver também que 'em vez de' pode ser usado (em certas circunstâncias) como 'ao invés de'.

Comment: Não sei onde queres chegar com essas considerações genéricas. Há frases em que _ao invés de_ pode ser substituído por _em lugar de_ sem grande impacto? Há de havê-las, tudo bem. Mas são uma pequena parte. Da [primeira meia dúzia](https://gist.github.com/cataphract/58595372703506799290b3bed52a356e) de exemplos que tirei do CETEMPúblico, só talvez o 5.o permite tal substituição.

Comment: Artefacto, qual a estatística permite você afirmar que "(...)são uma pequena parte(...)", esta que você cita no mesmo comentário? Há de haver outros lugares em que a língua portuguesa é praticada em sentido diferente daquele de Portugal e em que 'ao invés' de é usado livremente como sinônimo de 'em vez de'. Formalmente há diferenças como já ficou claro (e semelhanças). Qualifique seu discurso de modo que não seja exclusivo...